# MySQL-FULLTEXT pattern matching

Tags: php, html, mysql, full-text-search

I have an MySQL-query which is made out of `FULLTEXT`-indexes because I need a relevance ordering.
The disadvantage is that I need to have the pattern matching like

> `SELECT * FROM table WHERE colum LIKE %word%`

Is there any way to implement this in `FULLTEXT`-searches?

Comment: In full text search you can peform wildcard search using `*`. So say you have data as `aabbbbcc,bbbb,bbbbxyz` you can use Boolean mode as `match (column) against ('bbbb*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can use [MySQL full Text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html):

Here you need not have to break the bigger input string into an array to compare with each individual word.

Please refer the below examples to write your own:

> A phrase that is enclosed within double quote (“"”) characters matches
>
> only rows that contain the phrase literally, as it was typed.

I want to explain you about [Boolean Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html); But I advise you to please go through [Full Text Search using Query Expansion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html) also.

Let's look at the example table:

```
mysql> select * from articles;
+----+-----------------------+------------------------------------------+
| id | title                 | body                                     |
+----+-----------------------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PostgreSQL Tutorial   | DBMS stands for DataBase ...             |
|  2 | How To Use MySQL Well | After you went through a ...             |
|  3 | Optimizing MySQL      | In this tutorial we will show ...        |
|  4 | 1001 MySQL Tricks     | 1. Never run mysqld as root. 2. ...      |
|  5 | MySQL vs. YourSQL     | In the following database comparison ... |
|  6 | MySQL Security        | When configured properly, MySQL ...      |
+----+-----------------------+------------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ('"database comparison"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

+----+-------------------+------------------------------------------+
| id | title             | body                                     |
+----+-------------------+------------------------------------------+
|  5 | MySQL vs. YourSQL | In the following database comparison ... |
+----+-------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Order matters, when the words are quoted:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ('"comparison database"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

When we remove the quotes, it will search for rows, containing words "database" or "comparison":

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ('database comparison' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
| id | title               | body                                     |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PostgreSQL Tutorial | DBMS stands for DataBase ...             |
|  5 | MySQL vs. YourSQL   | In the following database comparison ... |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Order doesn't matter now:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ('comparison database' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
| id | title               | body                                     |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PostgreSQL Tutorial | DBMS stands for DataBase ...             |
|  5 | MySQL vs. YourSQL   | In the following database comparison ... |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

If we want to get rows, containing either word "PostgreSQL" or phrase "database comparison", we should use this request:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ('PostgreSQL "database comparison"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
| id | title               | body                                     |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PostgreSQL Tutorial | DBMS stands for DataBase ...             |
|  5 | MySQL vs. YourSQL   | In the following database comparison ... |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72f54/1)

Make sure, that the words, you are searching for, are not in the [list of stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html), that are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Yes use MATCH  AGAINST FULLTEXT SEARCH like this

SELECT * FROM tablename   WHERE MATCH (columnname) AGAINST (' value ');

if you want to search from multiple tables then mention the tablenames separating by commas

Comment: You have to make that field as a fulltext before running this query. To make this use the sql query    ALTER TABLE tablename ADD FULLTEXT(fieldname);

Comment: what version of mysql are you using if its 5.5 and lower than make sure your db engine is myisam and not innodb because fulltext search is not supported in versions 5.5 and lower, only if you have mysql version 5.6 then will this work and if you do this means that something else is the problem

Comment: yes the full text with innodb will work on mysql version 5.6. You are right.